# Python xpath - get information in the right order

Tags: python, xpath

first off, I'm sorry if the title is not very clear; I'm not too sure on how to explain what I want to do with the title; anyway.

I'm getting some information from a website; I already have the information that I want but when I run the script I get the output as follows:

```
Ivern Jungle
Starting Items                                                  
Hunter's Talisman
Refillable Potion
Warding Totem
First Goal                                                      


Stalker's Blade
Tracker's Knife
Boots of Speed
Hunter's Potion
Vision Ward
Sweeping Lens
Second Goal
```

When I want it to be like this:

```
Ivern Jungle

Starting Items                                                  
Hunter's Talisman
Refillable Potion
Warding Totem


First Goal                              
Stalker's Blade
Tracker's Knife
Boots of Speed
Hunter's Potion
Vision Ward
Sweeping Lens
Second Goal
```

I've tried some things with the code; and this is the only way that I can get it working as I want. `Ivern jungle` is a title; `Starting Items` is another title and `First Goal` another one; before I was getting first the titles and then the other information (the items). This is the code that I have right now.

```
        for build_names in guide_page.xpath(".//div[@class='build-container box-shadow-lb']"
                                            "/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]"):

            for title in build_names.xpath("div[1]/h2/text() | div[3]/div[1]/div/h2/text() | "
                                           "div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div/a/div[2]/span/text()"):
                print(title)
```

I'm getting most of the information from the `title` for loop because that's how I managed to get it right; if there is a more efficient way to do it; please let me know

By the way, that information is from a specific website but websites can change, from another specific website I get information like this:

```
Kled The Talker # Title
Kled Tank/Ad Top    # Title                                             
Mercury's Treads
The Black Cleaver
Titanic Hydra
Frozen Mallet
Dead Man's Plate
Guardian Angel
Kled Ad/LifeSteal   # Title                                             
Mercury's Treads
The Black Cleaver
Ravenous Hydra
Death's Dance
Maw of Malmortius
Guardian Angel
```

As you can see I don't get any spaces in between; if you go to the [first website](http://www.mobafire.com/league-of-legends/build/ivern-jungle-nature-strikes-unseen-s6-489822) you can see that in the items section there are notes on the right side of each title from the items section that; I think that those are the ones that put the spaces in the output because in the [second website](http://www.mobafire.com/league-of-legends/build/kled-s6-top-build-485170) there are no notes. Well, that is my main issue; how can I format the output? If I didn't explain myself too clear please let me know and I'll update the question, thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could navigate the tree quite a bit easier by using the class attributes more often. That way, you could rewrite your script like this:

```
for div in page.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "item-wrap")]'):
    print("\n{bar}\n{title}\n{bar}".format(
        bar="#"*20, 
        title=div.xpath('.//h2/text()')[0].strip()))
    print('\n'.join(x.strip() for x in div.xpath(
        './/div[contains(@class, "main-items")]//span/text()')))
```

Output excerpt:

```
####################
Starting Items
####################
Hunter's Talisman
Refillable Potion
Warding Totem

####################
First Goal
####################
Stalker's Blade
Tracker's Knife
Boots of Speed
Hunter's Potion
Vision Ward
Sweeping Lens

####################
Second Goal
####################
Rod of Ages
Boots of Mobility
Ionian Boots of Lucidity
Boots of Swiftness
Sorcerer's Shoes
Oracle Alteration
```

Those xpaths work equally well on the second page you linked to.

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much. If it's not too much to ask; above the `for` that I was using I kinda _did_ an `if` that was only displaying a block of code. In the html sometimes there are `divs` that have `style="display: block;` or `style="display: none;` I only want to use  `style="display: block;`, the main one; if you see [here](http://www.mobafire.com/league-of-legends/build/open-your-eyes-lee-sin-jungle-guide-393845) you can see that there are two pictures above the title with "Build 1" and "Build 2"; I only want to get information from "Build 1". How can I do this? Thanks

Comment: @fuhrerguxez that's not as easy: those attributes are dynamically added through jQuery. However, if "Build 1" is always listed before "Build 2" in the HTML, then you could get the `div` of "Build 1" with `page.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "build-container")]/div')[0]`. You should rebase any subsequent xpaths from that node then.

Comment: Alright, I got it working; I changed some things, I can't paste it as a comment because it would take much space I think; I'll test it thoroughly; thanks for your help man! :)